# Format tmux's pane_current_path

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to set my tmux window's title to be the current directory that I am in. Now `pane_current_path` is perfect for this, but it prints the full path in my machine.

Is it possible to run `pane_current_path` though some formatting and only print out the current directory?

Currently using it like this

```
setw -g window-status-current-format "#{pane_current_path}"
setw -g window-status-format "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tmux man page, under FORMATS section says:

> The `b:` and `d:` prefixes are basename(3) and dirname(3) of the variable respectively.

Following option should effectively change window's title to basename of current directory:

`setw -g automatic-rename-format "#{b:pane_current_path}"`

Answer (score 5):

(Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/32426739 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9757133)

This can be done if your shell has a 'precmd' hook (bash and zsh do); this hook would be setting tmux's pane title via escape sequence, and you'd use `#{pane_title}` instead of `#{pane_current_path}`.  For bash, add something like this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ -n "$TMUX" ]] && PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n -e "\e]2;${PWD##*/}\e\\"'
```